# cmake command line option

Tags: c, visual-studio, cmake

I am new to VS development and Cmake. 
I have used CMake-GUI to generate a visual studio solution and am able to build it successfully.

However, our code has now reached a stage where we can finally build & link into a binary. With multiple people checking in code, we want to do a nightly build and so I was thinking of writing a batch file for this.

However, I am trying to invoke cmake from command line and am running into issues.

In cmake-gui, in order to configure, I provide two values
Path of my source code
Path where binaries will be generated

However, when I try to run the same over command line (using the following command)

```
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -D CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR="D:\source_code" -D CMAKE_BINARY_DIR="D:\source_code\build\gen\host"
```

CMake throws up an eror : The source directory "D:\" is a file not a directory.

I tried the following variations too without any luck

```
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -D PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR="D:\source_code" -D PROJECT_BINARY_DIR="D:\source_code\build\gen
```

Can someone please guide me to the correct syntax.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess it is because backslashes are handled as an escape caracter within CMake.
You could try doubling the backslashes : `\\` or working with slashes `/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't try and set any of these variables on the command line.  They're automatically set by CMake the first time it reads the CMakeLists.txt.

Instead, you should *run* the CMake command from within the binary dir, and pass the path to the directory containing the top-level CMakeLists.txt.  So something like:

```
cd D:\source_code\build\gen\host
cmake -G"NMake Makefiles" D:\source_code
```

By the way, CMake's command line parsing isn't great (e.g. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17181954/2556117)).  I'd recommend avoiding leaving spaces after `-D` arguments.

Comment: but when I run the Cmake-GUI, I provide "Where is the source" and "Where is the binary" values? How would cmake know if I am using command line?

Comment: The binary dir is implied by *where* you execute the CMake command from.  The source dir is passed as an argument to the CMake command - in this case `D:\source_code`.

Comment: Also, once CMake has run the first time, it creates a cache file called CMakeCache.txt in the build folder root.  Subsequent runs of CMake can just be given the path to this build root.  So if you rerun CMake and are still in the build root, you can just do `cmake .` (all previous `-D` args are cached and don't need to be set again unless you want to change any of them).

Comment: Unfortunately, what you suggested does not work. If i run cmake the way you suggested, it throws up an error "CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to NMake Makefile". Before, I ran this command,I had run vcvars32.bat, can confirm that cl is available. The only thing that do work is that if i generate a cache file via gui first. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could be typo?  Your error message mentions "NMake Makefile", but the generator should be "NMake Makefiles" (with an "s").

Comment: yes it was a typo. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesnt. When it works its throwing up linker errors which I am not getting on a clean build. Let me debug this further. Thanks for your time

Comment: Hi Fraser, cmake isn't working for NMake. I have no problem If i generate a VC solution but if I run cmake (and I am running it as you have suggested) it throws up errors related to unable to find a build program. However, if i look closely inside the CMakeFiles folder a CMakeOutput.txt is generated which says that everything has compiled and linked perfectly. I am not sure whats wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Remove space between -D and parameter

```
 cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_SOURCE_DIR="D:\source_code" -DCMAKE_BINARY_DIR="D:\source_code\build\gen\host"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project, We used a CMake-GUI. But I created a shell script file to avoid repeatedly fill up the entries.

Sample gist is as follows.

```
cd <DIRECTORY_TO_BUILD> && <CMAKE-INSTALLATION-PATH>/bin/cmake.exe --build= "<BUILDSOURCE-PATH> -DQt5Widgets_DIR:PATH=C:/Qt/5.12.0/msvc2017/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets
```

I have started with cd else the script will create the build folder from where the script is run.