# How to set opencv release mode with cmake

Tags: opencv, cmake

It seems very easy when compiling opencv library for the release mode:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE ../
```

or `cmake DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:string=Release ../`
However, the created project is still in Debug mode, and I was wondering how I could do in order to make the project in a release mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration name is case-sensitive, and the CMake command line arg needs a `-` at the front. The arg type (i.e. `string` in your example) is optional, so the command should be:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

Comment: I am using Visual Studio

Comment: In that case, the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable is unused by CMake.  This is only applicable for single-configuration generators.  See [the docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) for further info.

Comment: I wonder if this is something to do with “[spacing in `-D` option in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14887438/4510033).”

Answer (score -1):

```
if(DEFINED CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} CACHE STRING “Choose the type of building”)
else()
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug CACHE STRING “Choose the type of build”)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} CACHE STRING “” FORCE)
```

cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..

Comment: Describe. Did, not spacing the `-D` and `C` fix it?